# No manual entry for xerces

Tags: command-line, apt, scripts, convert, xml

How do I install xerces so that I can use it for schema validation?

I've tried:

- libxerces-c-doc
- libxerces-c-samples
- libxerces-c3.2
- libxerces2-java
- libxerces2-java-doc

Probably it's installed, but `man xerces` gives no results:

```
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ man xerces
No manual entry for xerces
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$
```

Ah, I see:

> ```
> Download Xalan-Java.
>
> Set the Java classpath to include xalan.jar, serializer.jar, xml-apis.jar, and xercesImpl.jar -- or another conformant XML Parser
> ```
>
> -- (see Plugging in the Transformer and XML parser).
>
> ```
> Call java and the Process class with the appropriate flags and arguments (described below). The following command line, for example,
> ```
>
> includes the -IN, -XSL, and -OUT flags with their accompanying
>   arguments -- the XML source document, the XSL stylesheet, and the
>   output file:

```
java org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -IN foo.xml -XSL foo.xsl -OUT foo.out
```

there's no "xalan" command which is configured?

Comment: Based on apt-file search, the only available man page appears to be that for `xerces-c-sample`

Comment: FWIW, I found that it was easier to just write a Java program than mess around with the path variables in order to execute a collection of JAR's.